# Using a timestamp revision using bash and subversion

Tags: string, bash, svn, revision

I'm trying to provide a date approach for the revision option in subversion, which itself should be provided through a simple bash script.

```
 $ BLUBB="{'2014-06-15 22:00:23'}" 
 $ echo $BLUBB
 {'2014-06-15 22:00:23'}
 $ svn export myrepo/file.txt /tmp/ -r$BLUBB
 svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '{'2014-06-15'
```

Another try:

```
 $ svn export myrepo/file.txt /tmp/ -r"$BLUBB"
 svn: E205000: Syntax error in revision argument '{'2014-06-15 22:00:23'}'
```

I'm messing around with that. How's the correct approach?

According to http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html the syntax should be like this:

```
 $ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}
```

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: What format does `svn` expect the revision to be in? You should definitely be using the double quotes around your variable in any case.

Comment: Indeed, quotes around `BLUBB` are certainly correct. I believe your single quotes are incorrect. I think those are markers in the help documentation indicating they are literal characters not that you need them in your date string.

Comment: It seems, that you have to escape spaces within a string provided to the svn client. This applies to log messages "-m" as well as to the here mentioned provision of a date instead of a revision number to "-r".

Answer (score 2):

I have all `them` tryed via bash ***script.***

But the "!!!" marked ones do not work !

- ok: `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {15:30}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {15:30:00.200000}`
- **!!!**: `$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30"}`
- **!!!**: `$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30Z}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30-04:00}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530Z}`
- ok: `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530-0500}`

I tryed all thinkable combinations of escape sequence for the **"**, the **{** and the **WS**.

I tryed **'** instead of **"**. And **{{** instead of **{**, and even more, but nothing worked.

So I changed the script by adding

`... | sed -r 's/\s+/T/' | sed -r 's/\s+//'`

to convert

`{"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}`

into

`{"2006-02-17T15:30+0230"}`

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes and read [SVNBook | Revision Specifiers](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html):

> Revision Dates
>
> Revision numbers reveal nothing about the world outside the version
>   control system, but sometimes you need to correlate a moment in real
>   time with a moment in version history. To facilitate this, the
>   --revision (-r) option can also accept as input date specifiers wrapped in curly braces ({ and }). Subversion accepts the standard
>   ISO-8601 date and time formats, plus a few others. Here are some
>   examples.

- `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17}`
- `$ svn update -r {15:30}`
- `$ svn update -r {15:30:00.200000}`
- `$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30"}`
- `$ svn update -r {"2006-02-17 15:30 +0230"}`
- `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30}`
- `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30Z}`
- `$ svn update -r {2006-02-17T15:30-04:00}`
- `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530}`
- `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530Z}`
- `$ svn update -r {20060217T1530-0500}`

RTFM [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/)!

Comment: Bevor RTFM me this way, read my question again. It is more related to how to provide the revision date via bash script.